# Определение n популярных символов в файле

Tags: java

Интересует только  \public List getTopNPopularSymbols (int n)\. Всю голову сломал. Остальной код оставлю, вдруг пригодится. Естественно, вывод через List.

public class FileAnalyserImpl implements FileAnalyser {

```
 File file = new File("hello.txt");
    Map<Character, Integer> localMap;


    @Override
    public String getFileName() {
        String name = file.getName();
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowsCount () throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int lines = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines++;
        }
        return lines;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLettersCount () throws IOException {

            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);

            String str;
            int totalSymbols = 0;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                totalSymbols += str.length();
            }
            in.close();

            return totalSymbols;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Character, Integer> getSymbolsStatistics () throws IOException {

        Map<Character, Integer> characters = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                char[] line = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();

                for (Character character : line) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(character)){
                        if (characters.containsKey(character)) {
                            characters.put(character, characters.get(character) + 1);
                        } else {
                            characters.put(character, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null){
                scanner.close();
            }
        }
        localMap = characters;
        return characters;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Character> getTopNPopularSymbols (int n){

        int j = 0;
        while (j < n) {
            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Берете поток `entrySet` от карты частот символов, сортируете его по убыванию частот, оставляете `n` символов и возвращаете список символов:

```
public List<Character> getTopNPopularSymbols (int n) {
    if (localMap == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList(); // лучше возвращать пустой список
    }

    return localMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .limit(n)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Недавно Java изучать начал. Не все методы знаю, этот не нашёл.